# Node js error: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: javascript, express, node-modules, nodemon, node-dev

After importing the expressEdge I got stucked.

```js
const path =require('path');
const expressEdge = require('express-edge');

const express = require('express');
const app = new express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(expressEdge);
app.set("views", `${__dirname}/views`);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})
app.get('/about.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/about.html'));
})
app.get('/contact.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/contact.html'));
})
app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/post.html'));
})

app.listen(5000, () => { 
    console.log('App listening o port 5000');
})
```

while trying to introduce the expressEdge I got these error below:

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Globalwise\Desktop\nodejs-blog\index.js:11:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Try `app.use(expressEdge.engine);` instead

Comment: Thanks so much this works.

Answer (score 0):

When you `require('express-edge`), it brings in an object.  When you register the middleware you need to pass the `engine`.  You have two options...

Access the `engine` property from the required object

```js
const expressEdge = require('express-edge');
app.use(expressEdge.engine);
```

Or access the `engine` property on the `require`

```js
const expressEdgeEngine = require('express-edge').engine;
app.use(expressEdgeEngine);
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-edge